# Store Variables/Objects generated from Excel 2010 Macro when application closes

Tags: vba, excel, collections, excel-2010

I've created a macro enabled workbook to do some capacity modeling.  I capture an end user's assumptions and parameters then pass them through several functions.  This generates a chart and table of projected timelines to come up with capacity over a certain time frame.  Within the macro I'm creating objects like "Projects" or "Phases" or "Units" that are class modules.  Some of these are collections of other objects.  I'm trying to store these objects so when the workbook is reopened the program will not have to recreate them every time.  The simplest solution I can think of is to print everything everything to a hidden workbook with a `Workbook_BeforeClose()` sub then initialize on `Workbook_Open()`.  Didn't know if there was a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

A hidden workbook should be ok - I would set it to `xlVeryHidden` to stop (most) users from finding the datasheet.

If the workbook is specific to a particular user, and not to a spreadsheet, then you could use the registry to store/retrieve information

```
x = GetSetting(appname := "MyApp", section := "Startup", key := "Left", default := "25")
'Shorter: x = GetSetting("MyApp","Startup", "Left", 25)
SaveSetting appname := "MyApp", section := "Startup", key := "Left", setting := 50 
'Shorter: SaveSetting "MyApp","Startup", "Left", 50 
DeleteSetting "MyApp", "Startup" , "Left"
```

There's also `GetAllSettings` which will load a complete section into a two dimensional array with the name of the setting in `(arraypos,0)` and the value in `(arraypos,1)`